# How to secure a php file containing connection info (db pw, ssh pw) in Windows?

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I have a securly running web site in centOS (php,mysql,apache)

Somehow, My client wans to have a small portion (which just generating invoice, customers) of the application in Windows OS.

This new application operates without internet connection in daily operation and maybe every night it will upload data to main system and download data from main system.

My concern is how to secure SSH login userid/pw and mysql db userid/pw. since this application resides 
in windows

=========================================

My clients will own/operate windows system. 
since my application uses PHP on both sides. I want to secure configure.php file in windows so that my clients can not see SSH login userid/pw and mysql db userid/pw.

OR is there any better(secure) way to connect to centOS from windows and access mysql db?

Comment: Create unprivileged accounts for ssh and db with only reading. Even if this info is stolen it is not going to make more damage then hacked access to Windows host.

Comment: The little windows application should **not** have direct access to your database so wouldn't need a DB userid/password. The fact that your server is written in PHP shouldn't matter. Provide an `https:` web service with appropriate authentication (maybe SSH keys or an API key) so (a) there is less to protect and (b) compromise of the authentication is still restricted to _very_ few (and hopefully harmless) actions.